# A sum of the product of two binomial coefficients and an exponential function

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

This is related to a question I had answered here previously, but with an added wrinkle. I would like to find the sum
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-l}2^k\binom{2(n+1-j)}{k}\binom{-n-1}{n-k-l}.
\end{equation}

[Marko Riedel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/44883/marko-riedel) found the [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4390464/sum-of-product-of-exponential-function-and-two-binomial-coefficients) in the case that $l=0$. Is it possible to perform this sum for $l\neq0$? It seems that the generalization is not immediately clear, as the nonzero $l$ makes it difficult to make a change of variable that simplifies the calculation of the residue. Or is there a useful approximation that can be found?

Answer (score 3):

In the most general case, you are right : there is no explicit solution if $l\neq 0$.

However, forgetting combinatorics
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-l}2^k\binom{2(n+1-j)}{k}\binom{-n-1}{n-k-l}=\binom{-n-1}{n-l} \, _2F_1(2 j-2 n-2,l-n;l-2 n;2)$$ where appears the Gaussian hypergeometric function.

Answer (score 1):

We apply the technique which is used in the referenced answer from @MarkoRiedel and derive a summation formula with upper limit $l$ only, which is no longer dependent on $n$. We so can derive for small values of $l$ closed formulas. We show the following is valid for integers $0\leq l\leq n$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-l}2^k\binom{2(n+1-j)}{k}\binom{-n-1}{n-k-l}
=\frac{(-4)^n}{2^l}\sum_{q=0}^l\binom{l}{j}(-1)^q\binom{j+\frac{1}{2}\left(q-3-l\right)}{n}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

- Setting $l=0$ in (1) we obtain
  \begin{align*}
   \sum_{k=0}^{n}2^k\binom{2(n+1-j)}{k}\binom{-n-1}{n-k}=(-4)^n\binom{j-\frac{3}{2}}{n}
   \end{align*}
  which is in accordance with @MarkoRiedel's answer recalling the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- Setting $l=1$ in (1) we obtain
  \begin{align*}
   \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k\binom{2(n+1-j)}{k}\binom{-n-1}{n-k-1}=\frac{1}{2}(-4)^n\left(\binom{j-2}{n}-\binom{j-\frac{3}{2}}{n}\right)
   \end{align*}
- and similarly for other small values of $l$.

In the following we use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ of a series. We so can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> We start with the left-hand side of (1) and obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-l}}&\color{blue}{2^k\binom{2(n+1-j)}{k}\binom{-n-1}{n-k-l}}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-l}2^k\binom{2n+2-2j}{k}[z^{n-k-l}](1+z)^{-n-1}\tag{3.1}\\
> &=[z^n]\frac{z^l}{(1+z)^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^k\binom{2n+2-2j}{k}z^k\tag{3.2}\\
> &=[z^n]\frac{z^l(1+2z)^{2n+2-2j}}{(1+z)^{n+1}}\tag{3.3}\\
> &=[z^n]\underbrace{\frac{z^l(1+2z)^{2-2j}}{1+z}}_{A(z)}\left(\underbrace{\frac{(1+2z)^2}{1+z}}_{f(z)}\right)^n\tag{3.4}
> \end{align*}

The following is based upon G. P. Egorychev's Classic: *[Integral Representation and the Computation of Combinatorial Sums](https://bookstore.ams.org/mmono-59)*. We consider the functions
\begin{align*}
A(z)=\frac{z^l(1+2z)^{2-2j}}{1+z}\qquad\mathrm{and}\qquad f(z)=\frac{(1+2z)^2}{1+z}
\end{align*}
and derive a function $w=w(z)$:
\begin{align*}
w(z)=\frac{z}{f(z)}=\frac{z(1+2z)^2}{1+z}\qquad\qquad w^{\prime}(z)=\frac{1}{(1+2z)^2 }\tag{4.1}
\end{align*}

We apply the **substitution rule** (Rule 5, one-dimensional case) from section 1.2.2 in G. P. Egorychev's book as follows:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{[z^n]\left(A(z)\left(f(z)\right)^n\right)=[w^n]\left.\left(\frac{A(z)}{f(z)w^{\prime}(z)}\right)\right|_{z=g(w)}}\tag{4.2}
\end{align*}
with $g(w)$ the inverted function of $w=w(z)$ in (4.1).

> We apply (4.2) to (3.4) and obtain
> \begin{align*}
> [z^n]&\left(\frac{z^l(1+2z)^{2-2j}}{1+z}\left(\frac{(1+2z)^2}{1+z}\right)^n\right)\\
> &=[w^n]\left.\left(\frac{z^l(1+2z)^{2-2j}}{1+z}\,\frac{1+z}{(1+2z)^2}(1+2z)^3\right)\right|_{z=g(w)}\\
> &=[w^n]\left.\left(z^l(1+2z)\right)^{3-2j}\right|_{z=g(w)}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^l}[w^n]\left(-1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4w}}\right)^l(1-4w)^{j-\frac{3}{2}}\tag{3.5}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^l}[w^n]\left(1-\sqrt{1-4w}\right)^l(1-4w)^{j-\frac{3}{2}-\frac{l}{2}}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^l}[w^n]\sum_{q=0}^l\binom{l}{q}(-1)^q(1-4w)^{\frac{q}{2}+j-\frac{3}{2}-\frac{l}{2}}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{(-4)^n}{2^l}\sum_{q=0}^l\binom{l}{j}(-1)^q\binom{j+\frac{1}{2}\left(q-3-l\right)}{n}}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (1) follows.

**Comment:**

- In (3.1) we apply the *coefficient of* operator according to (2).
- In (3.2) we apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]T(z)=[z^p]z^qT(z)$. We also set the upper limit of the sum to $\infty$ without changing anything thanks to the *coefficient of* operator.
- In (3.3) we use the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (3.5) we derive the inverse representation $z=g(w)$ from
  \begin{align*}
  w=\frac{z(1+z)}{(1+2z)^2}\qquad\mathrm{take}\qquad z=\frac{1}{2}\left(-1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4w}}\right)
  \end{align*}
  and perform the substitution.